# Objective C Protocols

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Hi i am new to objective c and i am trying to implement the following.
There is a protocol that has a method. Then i create an object of that protocol in another class and in the third class i conform to protocol. Here is the code.

```
@protocol FirbaseUpdateDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)usersObtained: (NSArray *)users;

@end
```

Here is the first class,

```
#import "FirebaseDelegate.h"

@interface FirebaseConnection : NSObject
{
id delegate; // protocol object
}
-(void) loadUsers;

@end


@implementation UsersMessageListViewController

NSArray *allUsers;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
FirebaseConnection *con = [[FirebaseConnection alloc] init];
//con.delegate = self; // i can not assign value to protocol here.
[con loadUsers];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
@end
```

This is not happening.

Comment: Where are you setting the `delegate`?

Comment: //con.delegate = self; i commented this out because it gave me errors.

Comment: Because neither of those classes conform to that protocol.

Comment: they do, how is that?

Comment: *"This is not happening."* In what specific way is it not working?

Answer (score 1):

Your `delegate` property doesn't conform to your protocol. Try

```
@interface FirebaseConnection : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<FirbaseUpdateDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

In Objective-C `id` is a pointer to any Objective-C object. You must explicitly specify that it conforms to the protocol you want. Also, remember to set delegate properties as **weak** so as to avoid retain cycles.

Also, remember to make sure your class conforms to the protocol as well and implements its methods

```
@implementation UsersMessageListViewController () <FirbaseUpdateDelegate>

// stuff

-(void)usersObtained: (NSArray *)users 
{
    // do stuff
}

@end
```